# How filter by year on PostgreSQL 8.4?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM "vw_portal_gmp_almoxarifado" 
WHERE 'ano_movimento' = SELCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date);
```

return a error of syntax.

Comment: SELECT * FROM "vw_portal_gmp_almoxarifado" WHERE 'ano_movimento' between '2022-01-01' and '2022-12-31'

Comment: While not directly related to your issue but **Postgres 8.4  seriously**. That version reached *end of life* 8 years ago. You should really consider updating your version.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a SELECT to call a function.

Also `'ano_movimento'` is a [string constant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS). If that is supposed to be a column name, remove the single quotes.

```
SELECT * 
FROM "vw_portal_gmp_almoxarifado" 
WHERE ano_movimento = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date);
```

Comment: But, without a select, i have a error.

SELECT * 
FROM "vw_portal_gmp_almoxarifado" 
WHERE ano_movimento = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date)
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character = double precision
LINE 3: WHERE ano_movimento = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date)
                            ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Apparently the column `ano_movimento` is a varchar. Why are you storing a number in a varchar column?

Comment: only have year in this column, idk the reason to build this table like this. 
but thanks, man, I will change the type.

Comment: If you have a year in the column, the column should be defined as `integer`.